# Updating nested redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a reducer that receives an action with a payload that I need to update the state with. The problem is the data I need to update in the state is nested data.
I've added my reducer below with some comment and what i tried to do so far.

```
export default function(state=data, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_CONTACT_INFO':
      let appointment = state[action.appointmentIndex]; // This is the appointment that needs to be updated 
      appointment.notification.contactInfo = action.payload; // this is the data that needs to be updated with the payload. I tried updating it like this but then not sure how to add it to the state. 
      return state; // Somehow need to update the state with the new state
      break;
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Below is my initial data structure which I pass into the reducer as the default state.

```
 data = [
        {
        date: 'Friday, January 6',
        time: '4:00 PM-5:00 PM',
        notification:
          {
            contactInfo: [
              {
                displayMethod:"Phone Call",
                method:"Phone",
                value:"3473686552"
              },
              {
                displayMethod:"Email",
                method:"Email",
                value:"memedoe@gmail.com"
              }
            ]
          }
      },
      {
        date: 'Saturday, January 7',
        time: '2:00 PM-6:00 PM',
        notification:
          {
            contactInfo: [
              {
                displayMethod:"Phone Call",
                method:"Phone",
                value:"2123686552"
              },
              {
                displayMethod:"Email",
                method:"Email",
                value:"johndoe@gmail.com"
              }
            ]
          }
      }
    ];
```

The action.payload in the reducer data is the same structure as contactInfo array in one of the appointments. `[Object, Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All problems of this type may be solved using `react-addons-update` package. Read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

This case can be solved that way:

```
export default function(state=data, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_CONTACT_INFO':
      return update(state, {[action.appointmentIndex]:{notification: {contactInfo: {$set: action.payload}}}});
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow this works but its confusing as to how it works. I've read the docs but still not getting what this part is doing. {[action.appointmentIndex]:{notification: {contactInfo: {$set: action.payload}}}}

Comment: [action.appointmentIndex] is just a number so how is it able to know which object in the array to get based on what you have above

Comment: As it works you can mark it with tick (it'd be my first one, you know). And how it works? Hm, for me the API is clear - when your state is an array, you can get into one of its element by declaring its index in array as convention. Yes, thats a number but that's enough - index of array is a number, that's clear.

Comment: If I have `state = [1,2,3,4]` and want to change 3 to 33, my code will be `update(state, {[2]: 33})`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

With redux you never update the state. You will have to return a new state object, with the updated data.

In order to do that, you need to use either Object.assign() or the ES6 spread operator {...}

I have provided links to both:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Read up on the reducers here:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Pay specific attention to *We Dont Mutate the state* point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use object.assign to change the data in your store

```
const newstateobject = Object.assign({}, state[someIndex], {notification: Object.assign({}, state[someindex].notification, {contactInfo: action.payload})});

return Object.assign({}, state, {[someindex]: newstateobject);
```

Comment: I'm updating a specific appointment in the state not all appointments. You have state.appointment what is that ?

Comment: I changed my answer, didnt see that we were dealing with an array.

Comment: state.appointment is noting its not even part of the data structure as you can see. I presume you mean state[action.appointmentIndex] to get the specific appointment ?

Comment: Yes. Late at night here;) i hope i at least kicks you off in the right direction:) too tired to think straight now;)

Comment: let appointment = state[action.appointmentIndex];
      let contactInfo = appointment.notification.contactInfo;
      const appointment = Object.assign({}, appointment, {contactInfo: Object.assign({}, contactInfo, action.payload}));

      return Object.assign({}, state, {state.appointment: appointment});

Comment: error is Indicating something wrong with the structure.

Comment: You are defining appointment as a let and a const;) you cant define a variable twice

Comment: I get back 1 object now instead of two which is not what I'm after but it's close.

Comment: That makes sence, because we are only returning that one object. My bad:)

Comment: What about now?:)

Comment: I get back this structure Object {0: Object, 1: Object} instead of [Object, Object]